# Numpy columnwise subtraction; subtract (k,n) array from values in a (k,) array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have

```
x=np.random.random((3,10))
y=np.array([1,10,100])
```

and I want to subtract the values in each column of `x` from `y`. I can do this like so:

```
np.array([y]*10).T-x
```

However, this involves the creation of a new array of 10 times the size of `y` (in this case). I could also imagine using a for loop. Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just stack `y` vertically and subtract `x`. For example:

```
y[:, None] - x    # insert a new axis into y (creating a new view of y)
```

or

```
np.vstack(y) - x  # stack y vertically (creating a copy of y)
```

This works because `y` now has shape `(3, 1)` and so can be broadcast with your `x` which has shape `(3, 10)`.

`x` and `y` can be broadcast together if each trailing dimension (i.e. starting from the end of the shape tuple) of `x` is equal to the trailing dimension of `y`, or if one of the compared dimensions is 1. In this example, the trailing dimension of `y` was changed to 1, so that the two arrays are compatible.

Comment: Ah... So I could also `y.reshape(3,1)-x`

Comment: @atomh33ls absolutely, as long as it's the required shape.

Comment: `y[:,np.newaxis]` is another way of reshaping `y`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
>>> (y - x.T).T
array([[  8.79354250e-01,   5.30104393e-01,   7.78342126e-01,
          4.56857161e-02,   5.32181828e-01,   1.47155126e-01,
          3.39654176e-01,   3.72693537e-01,   4.32737024e-01,
          7.55366710e-01],
       [  9.53976069e+00,   9.51725133e+00,   9.00439583e+00,
          9.65411497e+00,   9.55728110e+00,   9.35189161e+00,
          9.72451832e+00,   9.20089714e+00,   9.60367043e+00,
          9.41722649e+00],
       [  9.99248465e+01,   9.96932738e+01,   9.93110996e+01,
          9.94116657e+01,   9.98695626e+01,   9.92118001e+01,
          9.93602275e+01,   9.99518088e+01,   9.98442735e+01,
          9.93865628e+01]])
```